extending ram of a PC gives memory failure
I have a PC with an i9-10900X CPU and the mainboard is link.
Currently, I have 2 32GB RAM modules installed, running at 3200MHz DDR4 (1.35v) each. I want to add more RAM, but I can't find the same model to install. So, I plan to buy 4 new 32GB RAM modules and give the old ones to a friend.
I ordered 2 "Corsair Vengeance LPX 2 x 32GB, 3200 MHz, DDR4-RAM, DIMM" kits, and they sent me 2 boxes, each containing 2 RAM modules. The RAMs inside each package are numbered as 1 and 2. When I install all RAM modules, I hear a memory failure beep. However, if I install only two RAM modules with different IDs (e.g., #1 and #2), it works, but it still gives a memory failure when installing modules with the same IDs.
My questions are: What do you think the problem is? Do you think it will work if I buy 4 "Crucial DDR4 RDIMM 2Rx8 3200 1x32GB" modules?

Update:
My friend and I have identical computers with the same configurations. Therefore, I gave him my 2x32GB RAM modules, and his computer worked perfectly with 128GB of RAM (I installed all 4 RAM modules in the white slots).
To clarify, I am unsure about the meaning of "2x32GB" storage capacity. There is also an option for 8x32GB on the website. Allow me to provide an example regarding the RAM IDs. In one package of 8x32GB RAM, there are 8 identical RAM modules, each labeled with a number from 1 to 8 sequentially. If I purchase two packages of these RAM modules (2 sets of 2x8GB), and I only want to use 64GB, I found that pairing RAM #1 from the first package with RAM #1 from the second package works. However, if I use any other combination of numbers with different labels next to each other, it results in 3 beeps, which was quite puzzling to me.
Finally, could anyone recommend a RAM model that is compatible with my motherboard and CPU, providing a total capacity of 128GB?
Thank you.

In the configuration list, you should only be looking at SxxU listings. There is no 128GB support. The ones that do are of the form Sxx(x)R and are only for the Xeon based workstations.

[Edit] your question to explain what you mean by "only two RAM modules with different IDs", two kits each containing 2 DDR4 module should result in you having 4 identical DDR4 modules. The Crucial and Corsair modules you are asking about should be identical other then perhaps frequency and timing delays.  I suspect your system simply does not support 128 GB of system memory.  So buying 4 32GB Corsair modules likely will result in the same error.

Per Ark and Dell, the volume of memory should be supported. I do note that that CPU is not listed as an option for that mobo (dell doesn't provide HCLs that i can find). Dell uses "Blink Codes" for preboot diagnostics, so based on this doc, can you get the specific error being detected? https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/precision-5820-workstation/precision_5820_om_pub/preboot-blinking-power-button-codes?guid=guid-cedeb3b8-064b-41df-b883-a39456d89249&lang=en-us

Has the CPU been changed from the original?

Thank you, I've never changed the CPU. I updated the descriptions, please let me know if you can assist me.

Your own link to the
Dell Precision 5820 Tower Owner's Manual
contains this informative note:

NOTE: 32 GB DIMMs are only supported on systems using Xeon W Series CPUs.

Your use of 32GB sticks is not supported according to the manual.
This explains your memory errors.
This is supported by Crucial's
Dell Precision 5820 (Intel Core Models) RAM & SSD Upgrades
which says that you have indeed the ability to have 128 GB of RAM.
However, Crucial only proposes 16GB sticks for your model, so 128 GB
would require 8 sticks of 16GB.
Crucial guarantees this information and has a very good return
policy.

He currently has a 2x32GB setup, so 32GB is supported. In the link given by him, you can  see there is support for this. However, it is capped at 64GB. The SxxU are the relevant entries (1 CPU, UDIMM). So even an 8x16GB setup should be unsupported according to Dell's own table.

@Silbee: The table also doesn't include 2x32GB. If Crucial says that 128GB is possible, I tend to believe them.

The table lists 2 2x32GB (S64Uc). OP also mentions his current configuration was 2x32GB.

In the Memory Matrix table (as per your link), only the last 7 entries are relevant for you. The ones of the form S##U. All the others are for the Xeon W version of the Dell Precision 5820 Tower.
Unfortunately, these entries show a maximum of 64GB of system memory.

Actually, I added 2x32GB memory from the same model (temporarily taken from another computer), and it worked perfectly with 128GB.

It's cool that it works. Technically, your CPU even supports upto 256GB. However, according to the Memory Matrix table, Dell doesnt officially support it. This makes it that much harder  for you. Since Dell's OEM memory works, you might be able to pick up some more of that (same part number).
